# Is that possible to display divs next to each other without floating?

Tags: css, html

I want to put several `div`s next to each other in one row. All `div`s have the same height.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fnbVZ/) is how this can be done using `float: left`.

Can this be done without using `float` ?

Comment: forgive my potential ignorance but wouldn't you use span in this case?

Comment: Doesn't work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fnbVZ/1/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depends, on what you want to do.
You can use `display: inline-block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/sygL9/

Comment: I didn't know about setting `font-size: 0` to the container. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

You could use display:inline-block. But unfortunately some browsers (some IE versions) don't support it.

http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: triggering hasLayout and setting display:inline accomplishes the same thing in IE. it is a hack though

Answer (score 2):

a `display: block` element is (effectively) going to have a line break at the end. One option that will let you keep block element styles, while putting it in the pageflow is set `display: inline-block` (of course, with [some additional work](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/) to get ie behaving)

Another option is to nest them, set them all to `position: relative`, and use the `left` rule to align them.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#together {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
 margin;left:10px;
 background-color:lightblue;
 width:500px;
 border:4px double blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="together" style="left:10px">first div</div>
<div id="together" style="left:520px">second div</div>
<div id="together" style="left:1030px">third div</div>
<div id="together" style="left:1540px">fourth div</div>
<div id="together" style="left:2050px">fifth div</div>
<div id="together" style="left:2560px">sixth div</div>
<div id="together" style="left:3070px">seventh div</div>
```

**Here you are, with seven divs in a row**

Comment: Using the same ID for multiple elements?! IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to change the divs to **span** elements, that would fix the problem without using CSS

```
 <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
```